# Hello, I am doing a machine learning assesment project in R where I have to perform multiple linear regression and write report on all my steps

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, normalization

So I did some data exploratory and found that the range of my features are variable, like some columns have range between 1 to 5, while other columns like 'square_feet' has range of 500 to 2000. In the pre-processing, I was planning to normalize the columns, so I have decided this approach where I only normalize the columns which have extreme range like 1000 to 10,000 and not the ones with range 0 to 10(for such columns with ordinal data, I will be creating dummy columns with 1 and 0, not sure If its needed, still in doubt). So should I normalize only specific columns or the whole data set? How should I treat the values I get after normalization, whic are continous values like -1.2341 and so on. Should I round them up or perfrom binning on them further? Please let me know the right approach, any help will be highly appreciated. Thank-you.

I have normalized few columns and stuck at the decision at should I do this to the whole data set.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to the site! May I suggest that you first try the linear regression without normalization, and then try it with? Pay special attention to things like p-values. What differences (or lack of differences) do you notice? Lastly, there's generally no reason to round inputs to regression, so let's leave that aside for now.

Comment: Hi thanks for you reply, I'll proceed with that and also should I normalize each column or only the ones that have higher range. As my assessment is more about the approach and less about the accuracy. I should have a logic. So I'm planning to create dummy variables for the ordinal numeric values and normalizing the columns that have higher range. Does it sound fine .? Thanks

Comment: When you just try it out, you will notice that it does not matter which variables are normalized or not for a linear regression :) (for a linear regression without penalty terms, that is)

Comment: Normalization does matter though? So I'll probably do it every column except the dummy columns created then